# How to get the C wire for Nest thermostat on Burnham series 2 gas boiler

Tags: thermostat-c-wire, boiler

I am trying to setup a smart thermostat for my boiler. Can you help me see where I can extract the C wire out from my boiler.
Thanks
[image: Control board on the boiler]

[image: Circuit diagram]

Answer (score 1):

There is your "C" wire connection:

[image: Wiring diagram]

If it's not brought out to the thermostat, run a new wire to it.

Comment: I measured the Voltage at the C and it was 28V instead of 24V (I put 1 pole on C, 1 pole on ground [not G]). Also, the G and R was connected (short by a wire), so I am kinda confused